# Running bash script in upstart .conf script

Tags: bash, startup, upstart

I would like run my bash script (kvm_manage) in startup, and it doesnt work. Here is my upstart .conf script:

```
      description "kvm start skript"

      start on local-filesystem
      stop on shutdown

      respawn 

      script
         exec /etc/kvm_manage start
      end script
```

I want run it with argument "start". It is possible? What should I change?

thanks for help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Running a command via `exec` with arguments is fine - see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#exec which gives such an example.

However, upstart will use `/bin/sh` not `bash`, so if your script needs bash you'd need something like

```
script
    exec bash -c '/etc/kvm_manage start'
end script
```

**Update:** See also the suggestion in the comments from Guss to use the `exec` stanza instead for simple cases:

```
exec bash -c '/etc/kvm_manage start'
```

Or if `kvm_manage` is an executable with a she-bang (`#!/bin/bash`), then simply:

```
exec /etc/kvm_manage start
```

Comment: `script` is used for running multiple commands, I think in this case its better to use the `exec` stanza instead. Its actually quite similar to the above example: just drop the `script` parts and leave only `exec bash -c '/etc/kvm_manage start'`. Also, if kvm_manage is an executable with a she-bang, then you don't even need that, just use `exec /etc/kvm_manage start`.